# NextJS production build not creating the .next/BUILD_ID

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

I'm encountering random occurrences of the `.next/BUILD_ID` file not being generated on a successful build.  The issues started 3 days ago and I've been rebuilding the same commit multiple times to try and identify why.

The build is being done within the docker base `node:20-alpine3.17` and is transpiling typescript along with using yarn in place of the normal npm calls.  I haven't encountered any build errors when the `BUILD_ID` file is missing and when the container is launched it fails on start up because of the verification that next is doing to ensure the .next folder has been built with the optimizations for production.

What would cause a next build to succeed but not produce a `BUILD_ID` file in the `.next` folder?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.17
RUN apk -U upgrade
WORKDIR /app
COPY source.tar.gz ./
RUN tar -xhzf source.tar.gz --strip-components=1 && rm -f source.tar.gz
RUN npm update -g npm node && npm install --global yarn --force
RUN yarn && yarn compile-ts && yarn build
RUN rm -rf /app/.next/cache
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm start",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "compile-ts": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@simbathesailor/use-what-changed": "^2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^7.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "scheduler": "^0.23.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "device": "^0.3.12",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.8",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^4.0.2",
    "minify-css-string": "1.0.0",
    "modern-normalize": "^1.1.0",
    "next": "^13.4.1",
    "next-images": "^1.8.4",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^8.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "pure-react-carousel": "^1.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-avatar-editor": "13.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-grid-system": "^8.1.8",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "react-scrolllock": "^5.0.1",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "react-sticky-table": "^5.1.11",
    "react-stickynode": "^4.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.3.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Start server by using npm run dev not npm run start . Or make a build npm run build . More info here
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-export-no-build-id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).